# Command vue init requires a global addon

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

When I tried to `vue init webpack test-app`,  I got the following error:

```
Command vue init requires a global addon to be installed.
Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-init and try again.
```

This is what I did to install **vue cli** v3 beta6
`npm install -g @vue/cli`

This is the tutorial I followed
https://itnext.io/getting-started-vue-js-and-visual-studio-code-6990f92e918a

Apparently, the tutorial does not need to install `@vue/cli-init`. I am wondering why and how to solve this issue.

Side Notes: When I install like this `npm install -g vue-cli` it works as expected. I have found that vue-cli is a stable 2.9.x version.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at [vue-cli repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) I see two different ways of scaffolding vue projects.

The **v3** (beta) version, installed as `npm install -g @vue/cli`, creates projects using the following command:

```
vue create my-project
```

While the version **2.9.x**, available at [master branch](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/master), is installed as `npm install -g vue-cli` and it allows projects scaffolding with the following:

```
vue init <template-name> <project-name>
```

for example:

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

So, in your scenario, for **v3** version you should use: `vue create test-app`.

[Here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/using-new-vue-cli-3/) you can find further information.

Comment: Thank you!!! I spent almost an hour trying to understand why `vue init` would not work. `vue create` works perfectly.

Comment: You should be able to use the cli without corrupting the global state... this is not a good solution, even if it's the best currently available

Answer (score 16):

From the vue-cli website, Vue CLI 3 uses the same `vue` binary , so it overwrites Vue CLI 2 (`vue-cli`). So if you need the legacy `vue init`you should install the global bridge

```
npm install -g @vue/cli-init
# vue init now works exactly the same as vue-cli@2.x
```

Answer (score 6):

Please install `npm install -g @vue/cli-init.` Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me,

```
npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global
```

Link: https://v4.cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html

Answer (score 0):

Just install `@vue/cli-init` globally like this:

```bash
npm install --global @vue/cli-init
```