# how to use vue-cli install the other vue version not latest

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I want to use vue-cli to initialize my vue project, but the vue and wepack version is the latest, This is not what I want, The older version is what I want, So I want to know how to install other versions of vue or webpack using vue-cli not the latest, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming this is because you have installed latest `vue-cli` which is currently `3.0.0-beta.10` and `vue init` is no longer the standard way of initiating new project.

So, in your scenario, for v3 version you should use: `vue create test-app`.

Though if you still like to use `vue init` then do either of it:

- See if things can work by doing what is suggested by @RuChernChong (I have not tried it)
- Or, just reinstall the old `vue-cli` by just running `npm install -g vue-cli@2.9.3`,

Side Note: You may need delete latest v3 manually if above mentioned suggestions doesn't work. Just run `which vue` you will find where v3 is installed and delete it manually and then run `npm install -g vue-cli@2.9.3`. Hope this should help.

Other places you can find help:

- Check kinda related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769310/1292050)
- Or, check how to use new v3 CLI
  [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/using-new-vue-cli-3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `vue init <template> <project-name>`

If you want to build using the `webpack` template, then

```
vue init webpack webpack-example
```

Depending on your current system, you might have to install an additional package for the above command to work.

```
npm install --global vue-init
```

Comment: It's 2022 now so not sure what all has changed but now I also had to install globally @vue/cli-init to use the webpack template in this way. There are a few more questions/options to choose but it basically works the same and it installs vue 2.5.2 which is what I needed to follow a vue 2 tutorial.